# Storyboards vs Navigational Path Map vs State/Activity Diagram

Tags: storyboard, uml

Although I've read that state and activity diagrams are more suitable for modelling an application when it is state based and the user's experience does not follow a pre-defined route, it is still unclear to me when one should use storyboards over navigational path maps ( or vice versa) as a design tool.

Could someone please explain when it would be ideal to use each type of UML diagram, (i.e. for a certain type of application one might be more suitable over the other, or when one would like to express different aspects of the user experience ) as I haven't really found good sources which compare and contrast these UML diagrams.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for ways to model the user experience in the form of diagrams.

If you want to model the user experience, with a *focus on providing an overview of the screens (or web pages)*, I would recommend to use a UML "**state machine diagram**", maybe more than one. Each state represents a screen or a popup and each transition represent a user action. See [agilemodeling.com](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/uiFlowDiagram.htm) and my own paper ["Which UML models should we make?"](http://www.admiraalit.nl/admiraal/WhichUMLmodels.pdf) (section "Navigation Map", page 12).

There are several ways of drawing navigation maps and a state machine diagram is just one way (but this diagram type can also be used for other purposes).

If you want to model the user experience, with a *focus on use cases*, i.e., if you want to model how the user navigates through the application to accomplish a certain task , I would recommend to use a UML "**activity diagram**" for each use case. The actions in the activity diagram more or less correspond to the steps of the use case (depending on how much UI-specific information you have in the use cases). For an example, see ["Which UML models should we make?"](http://www.admiraalit.nl/admiraal/WhichUMLmodels.pdf), page 10.

I don't know your definition of a storyboard, but in my perception, an activity diagram can be used to make one (but this diagram type can also be used for other purposes).

In the case you describe, an application that "is state based and the user's experience does not follow a pre-defined route", I would stick to state machine diagrams and not create any activity diagrams.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at these references!

Comment: Useful reference paper

Answer (score 2):

A story board comes into play once you got an idea what should be done. Then you can concentrate on the how-to using story boards and wire framing. As part of the design process both will influence the what which is shown best in activity diagrams. You can also use state diagrams to show transitions between user dialogs. But from a personal feeling they are a bit too techie and more likely to appear when you reach the coding phase. Using more picture oriented ways like story boards/wire frames help to shed another light on the use case. They all are part of the whole design process.

There is always a risk of over-doing things in the one or other way. So there is no rule-of-thumb here. It's just experience that can help.

Comment: thanks, and what about navigation path maps?

Comment: Not really my expertise, but they are used together with wire frames so you know how to navigate. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_wireframe

Comment: thanks, til take a look!